# Spaces in Cygwin/bash aliases?

Tags: bash, cygwin, alias

I am attempting to set up aliases for my Cygwin bash shells, to run programs contained in the standard Windows C:\Program Files subdirectories.  Unfortunately, the alias command really doesn't like spaces in a directory name, and nothing I've tried seems to work.  I'm trying to get the following running:

```
alias npp='/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe'
```

I am currently cheating and using a soft link, but I would prefer to use an alias.

Comment: A horrendous workaround for this problem would be of course replace “Program Files” with “Progra~1” (“dir /x C:\”) tells you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Escape Characters:

`alias npp="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`

Edit: Note the change from single to double quotes as well.

Comment: It almost works.  However, instead of bringing up Notepad++, it shows some sort of prompt character ( a > ) in the terminal.  I'm using rxvt, if that is important.

Comment: I believe the double quotes I have are imporant because they allow for usage of escape characters (and variables for the matter). Make sure you changed your single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Disregard previous comment.  Problem was caused by poor typing skills on my part.  Thanks...

Comment: @mkClark - For confirmation, does it work with single quotes now?

Answer (score 0):

While the answer above will solve the problem, here is another thing you can try:

Use [`junction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction) utility from microsoft to create a symlink `"C:\ProgramFiles"` to `"C:\Program Files"` (and "C:\ProgramFiles86" to "C:\Program Files (x86)")

```
Sample usage:
C:\>junction C:\ProgramFiles "C:\Program Files"
```

Amusingly, the link I gave above mentions the exact same case of "Program Files" having a space in it.