# Pb with spaces in .bashrc ALIAS

Tags: cygwin, alias, spaces

I have exactly the same pb :
[Spaces in Cygwin/bash aliases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928312/spaces-in-cygwin-bash-aliases)

i'm using rxvt in bash mode and i'm trying to setup my alias in the .bashrc
If i follow the answer of the previous post my alias look like this:

```
alias ma="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/bin/maya.exe"
```

but i get this :

```
$ ma
: No such file or directoryiles/Autodesk/Maya2011/bin/maya.exe
```

i also try this synthax :

```
alias ma="/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/bin/maya.exe"
```

but it give me

```
$ ma
bash: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory
```

So if you guys have any idea on how to solve this, it would be great !

Cheers

sk

PS : i Edit my question because i'm not allowed to answer my own question

Thanks for your help guys !

i try to replace with the Progra~1 synthax and it doesn't work. So i was wondering if the pb comes from the space character.

so i try to create an alias to an .exe that doesn't need space character:

```
alias py1="/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe"
alias py2='/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe'
alias py3=/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe
alias py4='cd /cygdrive/c/Python27'
```

and i also get an error

```
    $ py1
    : No such file or directorypython.exe
    $ py2
    : No such file or directorypython.exe
    $ py3
    : No such file or directorypython.exe
    $ py4
    : No such file or directoryn27
```

so i wonder if the cygwin synthax for creating Alias is the same than the Linux one ?
or maybe there is something wrong with windows 7 x64 ? i really don't know where the problem come from ?

Answer (score 3):

Two possible workarounds:

1. Replace `Program Files` in your path with `Progra~1`, or
2. Make a symlink to remove spaces: `mklink /D c:\programs "c:\Program Files"` (afair, `mklink` is only present starting from Vista)

Comment: thanks for your help please check my post edition to get the full answer !

Answer (score 2):

Use an advanced editor like the free [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to modify the not DOS format .bashrc file. Don't use Microsoft's Notepad becouse interprets CRLF as a newline. While on Mac/Unix newline is just LF. if you have mistakenly converted and saved the file, you can find a copy of the original in cygwin\etc\skel.

To show the End of Line symbol used in a file, in Notepad++ use View -> Show Symbol -> Show End of Line.

Comment: This is excactly the source of the error !!! now everything works perfectly , i can have the same synthax beetween windows and ubuntu in my .bashrc ! thanks again for your great support :)

Comment: dos2unix.exe can convert a file with DOS format to unix format. This will solve the problem. The DOS format with Cyngwin often causes strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easier solution is to move Autodesk directory from C:\Program Files\ to C:\

Comment: thanks for your help please check my post edition to get the full answer !

Comment: I have Windows 7 32 Bit and if I write 
$ alias ma="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe" works!!!

Comment: Are you inserted alias code line into .bashrc file that is stored in ...cygwin\home\[yourusername]? Before close and reopen cygwin.

Comment: well i know something was strange :) I try alias ma="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe" and it give me an error. I write my alias in C:\cygwin\home\seb\.bashrc. Maybe i will try to reinstall cygwin , rxvt or cygwin/X is maybe the source of the pb ? thanks again for your help !

Comment: What's the mesage error? In your pc do you have wordpad.exe in the same path? Try this: in the bash after write alias ma="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe" before write only alias and write me the result.

Answer (score 0):

well i reinstall cygwin and things are now going better

when i only put this

```
alias wp="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe"
```

it now works ! but when i enter this

```
alias wp="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe" 
alias nk="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Nuke6.2v1/Nuke6.2.exe"
```

the wp give me an error

```
$ wp
: No such file or directoryiles/Windows NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe
```

but the nk alias works

so i figure that the problem was coming from the carriage return character created by notepad, i try this :

```
alias wp="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Windows\ NT/Accessories/wordpad.exe" nk="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Nuke6.2v1/Nuke6.2.exe" ma="/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Autodesk/Maya2011/bin/maya.exe"
```

and it works perfectly !

so in my case the pb is i guess the carriage return created in notepad, it may create an hidden character that cygwin doesn't like. i'll try to edit my .bashrc in vi directly in order to see if the pb come from notepad or directly from carriage return.

it would be interesting if you check that if this syntax works on your computer

```
alias myalias1="/cygdrive/c/.../pgm1.exe" 
alias myalias2="/cygdrive/c/.../pgm2.exe" 
alias myalias3="/cygdrive/c/.../pgm3.exe"
```

thanks again for your support !

cheers !

Answer (score 0):

+1 for file type to save .bashrc, .profile etc. with Cygwin: for example with TextPad be sure to select file type Unix on Save.  Without it .... all sorts of bizareness.